# How can I downgrade Microsoft .net from 4.7.0 to 4.6.2 version

Tags: windows, .net-framework

I searched several pages not found a defined answer. I have a test case where my code needs .net 4.6.2 but we are migrating to cloud so we were asked to use windows server 2016 which has .net 4.7.03 version but I need to degrade it to 4.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Microsoft blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2016/03/04/mailbag-how-to-revert-to-older-versions-of-the-net-framework-4-family/) the only way to downgrade is to uninstall the current version and (after that) install the older version.